# Updating messages with inline keyboards using callback queries

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to update message in chat with inline keyboard but can't understand how to receive a *inline_message_id* or if it only for inline queries how I can determine *chat_id* and *message_id* for using it on [editMessageText(*args, **kwargs)](https://pythonhosted.org/python-telegram-bot/telegram.bot.html) in class *telegram.bot.Bot*?

my code example (part of it):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, InlineQueryHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

tokenid = "YOUR_TOKEN_ID"

def inl(bot, update):
    if update.callback_query.data == "k_light_on":
        #func for turn on light res = k_light.on()
        bot.answerCallbackQuery(callback_query_id=update.callback_query.id, text="Turning on light ON!")
        bot.editMessageText(inline_message_id=update.callback_query.inline_message_id, text="Do you want to turn On or Off light? Light is ON")
        #hardcoded vars variant
        #bot.editMessageText(message_id=298, chat_id=174554240, text="Do you want to turn On or Off light? Light is ON")
    elif update.callback_query.data == "k_light_off":
        #func for turn on light res = k_light.off()
        bot.answerCallbackQuery(callback_query_id=update.callback_query.id, text="Turning off light OFF!")
        bot.editMessageText(inline_message_id=update.callback_query.inline_message_id, text="Do you want to turn On or Off light? Light is ON")
        #hardcoded vars variant
        #bot.editMessageText(message_id=298, chat_id=174554240, text="Do you want to turn On or Off light? Light is OFF")
    else:
        print "Err"

def k_light_h(bot, update):
    reply_markup = telegram.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("On", callback_data="k_light_on"), telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Off", callback_data="k_light_off")]])
    ddd = bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Do you want to turn On or Off light?", reply_markup=reply_markup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #
    updater = Updater(token=tokenid)
    ### Handler groups
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    # light
    k_light_handler = CommandHandler('light', k_light_h)
    dispatcher.add_handler(k_light_handler)
    # errors
    updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)
    updater.start_polling()
    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT
    updater.idle()
```

When I run it I have an error:

```
telegram.ext.dispatcher - WARNING - A TelegramError was raised while processing the Update.
root - WARNING - Update ...
... caused error "u'Bad Request: message identifier is not specified'"
```

I checked var *update.callback_query.inline_message_id* and it was empty. When I tried *bot.editMessageText* with hardcoded vars *chat_id* and *message_id* it worked well.

Do I need save in DB (for all users) vars *chat_id* and *message_id* when  they run command /light and then when they press inline button I need read from DB this value or I can use some simpler method for editing messages?

Comment: I think you don't need try receive `inline_message_id`.
From inline keyboard callback you receive `message_id`.

Can you list your update.callback_query? I think `update.callback_query.message.message_id` will be there

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, `message_id` there but I need `chat_id` too for non inline messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pass `message_id` instead of `inline_message_id` to `editMessageText`.

So the solution for you is this:

```python
bot.editMessageText(
    message_id = update.callback_query.message.message_id,
    chat_id = update.callback_query.message.chat.id,
    text = "Do you want to turn On or Off light? Light is ON"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, message_id is OK, but error sad that `Bad Request: Wrong inline message identifier specified` when I tried to use `message_id` instead of `inline_message_id` I have an error about empty `chat_id`. How can determine `chat_id`? I'm using bot not in inline mode.

Comment: @Alex btw [RTFM](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types) :)

Refer to [callbackquery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) and [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), all the info is there.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new to OOP in python and didn't know how I can find available types. I tried to found it in library documentation and with python dir(). Now it's clear thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this

```
    try:
        query.edit_message_reply_markup(reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard))
    except:
        return
```